# ¿Por qué no se ejecuta un component después de un guard?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Estoy implementando guards en mi aplicación, funciona de manera general de la siguiente manera:

- Página de login (usuario y contraseña)
- Se crea el token y se almacena
- Se muestra el tab1 con una lista de eventos, al hacer clic en cualquier evento se abre una ventana modal que es un component con la información específica de ese evento.

Estos pasos mencionados son el escenario ideal, pero sucede que no, al hacer clic en un evento en específico me muestra el siguiente error:

> Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-content'.

Buscando el error, se soluciona agregando CommonModule en components.module.ts, y claro que está, de no ser así nunca habría funcionado la aplicación antes de implementar el guard.

Haciendo pruebas, tengo que ir al tab2 (eventos por categoría), regresar al tab1, clic en cualquier evento y ya se muestra como debe ser...

¿Qué se carga cuando me muevo al tab2?

Aquí algo de código:

app-routing.module.ts:

```
{
    path: 'main',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule),
    canLoad:[UsuarioGuard]
  }
```

usuario.guard.ts:

```
constructor(private usuarioService:UsuarioService){}

  canLoad(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    return this.usuarioService.validaToken();
  }
```

usuario.service.ts:

```
async cargarToken(){
    this.token = await this.storage.get('token') || null;
  }

  async validaToken():Promise<boolean>{

    await this.cargarToken();

    if(!this.token){
      this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/login');
      return Promise.resolve(false);
    }

    return new Promise<boolean>(resolve => {

      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token
      });

      this.http.get(`${URL}/API_3/userTkn`, { headers })
      .subscribe(resp => {
        if(resp['ok']){
          this.usuario = resp['usuario'];
          resolve(true);
        }
        else{
          this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/login');
          resolve(false);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

**La solución es cambiar canLoad[UsuarioGuard] por canActivate[UsuarioGuard]**

Comment: No entiendo el problema. ¿El guard no está funcionando correctamente? También, puedes borrar los enunciados que no clarifiquen o describan el problema actual que tienes o que ya resolviste.

Comment: @GustavoSánchez el guard funciona correctamente, la cuestión es que al entrar al tab1 y al abrir cualquier modal, la información no es cargada, si quito `canLoad:[UsuarioGuard]` de la ruta, el modal muestra la información como debe ser, por la tanto, creo que al ejecutar el guard en main únicamente da permisos para ejecutar los tabs, no sus componentes, lo que me resulta extraño es que si voy al tab2 y regreso al tab1, el componente modal ya muestra la información como debe ser.

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar el código de `tab1`, `tab2` y el enrutamiento de `TabsModule?

Comment: @GustavoSánchez código agregado.

Comment: Tal vez tiene que ver con que estás utilizando `async` en  `ngOnInit() {...}` en `tab1`, que según la documentación, para el uso de `LoadingController` no es necesario. Puedes instanciarlo sin el uso de `await` y utilizar sus métodos `.present()` y `.dismiss()`: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/loading/LoadingController/#usage

Comment: Gracias por responder @GusSánchez y @GusSL, la solución es cambiar `canLoad[UsuarioGuard]` por `canActivate[UsuarioGuard]`, saludos.